# UITableViewCellStyleValue1 - keep detail text label width uniform

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have this problem:

[image]

See the 5th row down... the detail text label of the cell is being squashed to the right to make room for the text label.

Any idea how to make all the detail text label's uniform in size? So that the whole of its content is shown? Thank you.

(PS: if anyone knows how to default a table to scrolling from the bottom up then that would be much appreciated too...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the way that Value1 works. I would suggest that you subclass UITableViewCell and override layoutSubviews so that you can fix the width of textView and detailTextView frames.

Comment: aha! layoutSubviews... brilliant. :) that way I can access the frame property. :) thanks